# How to change active material list material list item color of angular components?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-html, dart-webui

[image]I am trying to display `material-list-items` of `material-list` with a background color `$mat-amber-A400`but while click on any of the `material-list-item` it changes the color to `light-grey`. How can I apply `background-color` 
to `$mat-amber-A400` color even on click of items.

app_component.html

```
<material-list class="name-card" *ngFor="let item of names">
            <material-list-item class="names">
                <span class="first">{{item.first}}</span>
                <span class="second">{{item.second}}</span>
                <material-chips><material-chip class="my-theme" [removable]="false"></material-chip>
                    <material-chip class="my-theme" [removable]="false"></material-chip>
                </material-chips>
            </material-list-item>
        </material-list>
```

app_component.scss

```
material-list material-list-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

material-list material-list-item:hover, material-list-item:active, material-list-item:visited {
  background-color: $mat-amber-A400;
}

.name-card {
  background-color: $mat-amber-A400;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  margin: 16px;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Try prefixing the selectors with `:host ::ng-deep `

Comment: `:host ::ng-deep material-list material-list-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: $mat-amber-A400;

}

:host ::ng-deep material-list material-list-item:hover, material-list-item:active, material-list-item:visited {
  background-color: $mat-amber-A400;
}` none of the code works

Comment: by removing `material-list` nothing works, including `material-list` the code effects on hover but while click on item `background-color` remains same `light-grey`

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my comments, I was completely on the wrong track.

Comment: So, help me with the right one

Answer (score 1):

```
material-drawer material-list-item:hover, 
material-list-item:active,
material-list-item:visited {
  background-color: $mat-amber-A400; 
}
```